# Create a chart for each pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, charts, pivot

In my active sheet I have two Pivot table (PivotTable1 and PivotTable2) sometimes they could be more though.
I am trying to add a chart for each PT in the active sheet. So far I came up with this code but it is giving me 4 charts 3 blank ones and a correct one if one of the PT is selected.

```
Sub CreateChart1()

Dim pivot As PivotTable, sh As Worksheet, nrp As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For nrp = 1 To sh.PivotTables.Count

 Set pivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(nrp)
    For Each pivot In sh.PivotTables
        Charts.Add
        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=pivot.Parent.Name
    Next pivot
Next nrp

End Sub
```

Can somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Nick.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting four charts even though you only have two pivot tables because you have two loops and only need one.

The inner loop `For Each pivot In sh.PivotTables` loops through each pivot table, as does the outer loop `For nrp = 1 To sh.PivotTables.Count`. So you'll get 2 charts for each pivot table.

Instead of using `Charts.Add` I suggest using [`ChartObjects.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobjects.add), which creates an embedded chart and where you can control the placement and size.

Then you also need to `SetSourceData`.

An example might look like this:

```
Sub AddPivotChart()
    Dim pivotTbl As PivotTable, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each pivotTbl In ws.PivotTables
        Dim chtObj As ChartObject
        Set chtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(50, 50, 200, 200) ' adjust as needed

        chtObj.Name = pivotTbl.Name
        chtObj.Chart.SetSourceData pivotTbl.TableRange1
    Next pivotTbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Big Ben Thanks a lot buddy